# Persistent api keys for onedrive embedded excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, onedrive, web, embedded

I have a site for a golf tournament that is literally just a series of embedded excel worksheets. I used the embed tool built into the web interface for one drive (right click file -> embed -> customize how this embedded workbook will appear to others) in order to get a base url and start generating embedded iframes for different worksheets. The embedded code looks like this:

```
<iframe width="402" height="346" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=8EFFBCC36AA48391%216812&authkey=%21AEvosjJL7TLS7Dg&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False&wdHideGridlines=True&wdHideHeaders=True&wdDownloadButton=True&wdInConfigurator=True"></iframe>
```

Within the url are two important get parameters: `resid` and `authkey` without which none of the other code matters. I use this function to generate a url:

```
function setURL(sheet) {
        const resid = "8EFFBCC36AA48391%216812";
        const authkey = "%21AEvosjJL7TLS7Dg";
        const iframe = document.getElementById("excel");
        const url = `https://onedrive.live.com/embed?`
                  + `resid=${resid}&authkey=${authkey}`
                  + `&em=2&wdAllowInteractivity=False`
                  + `&Item=${encodeURI(sheet)}`
                  + `&wdHideGridlines=True&wdDownloadButton=True`
                  + `&wdInConfigurator=True`;
        iframe.setAttribute("src", url);
    }
```

It works perfectly when the `resid` and `authkey` don't change. But the excel sheet is updated frequently, and I have yet to figure out how to avoid disabling or changing those two variables. There are three ways to update the excel workbook:

1. Copy and paste the new version of the worksheet into OneDrive on the Windows Desktop, overwriting it.
2. Edit the copy within the Windows OneDrive folder on the Windows Desktop.
3. Click and drag the new version of the worksheet into the OneDrive interface in the web portal.

I have experimented with the first two, and sometimes the authkey and resid get changed, sometimes they don't. Note: the filename is always identical.

Is there anything I can do to pin the `authkey` and `resid` so that I don't have to worry about changing the code too often?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved via Microsoft support. It turns out that this is the default behavior but there was a bug in the installation. Reinstall of Office/OneDrive solved it.